# как переменной присвоить значение файла json? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

есть файл json с городами мне нужно

```
в контроллере
сделать вида  
$city = file_get_contents("app/Json/city-ua.json");//не работает //file_get_contents(app/Json/city-ua.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: так может путь надо указывать от корня проекта как-то, с использованием соответствующих констант, или еще чего-то ?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте хелпер ларавеля `base_path()` (возвращает абсолютный путь от корня проекта).

```
$path = base_path('app/Json/city-ua.json');
$city = file_get_contents($path);
```